# Scraper - An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python

Good morning,

Twitter scraper, working fine for months now gets the below error. It also pulls limited Tweets for the date range. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I am getting when running on spyder 5.0.5 on Python 3.8.

It was working fine up until September.

**ERROR CODE**

```
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 32, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 60, in run_until_complete
    f = asyncio.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 673, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 32, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 60, in run_until_complete
    f = asyncio.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "C:\Users\james.coldman\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 673, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

**FULL SCRIPT IN USE**

```
import nest_asyncio
import twint
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
import random
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
nest_asyncio.apply()


RE_EMOJI = re.compile('[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]', flags=re.UNICODE)
def strip_emoji(text):
    return RE_EMOJI.sub(r'', text)

def sentiment_score(tweet):
    score = analyser.polarity_scores(tweet)
    return score['neg'], score['neu'], score['pos'], score['compound']

def scrape(search_term, start_date, end_date):
    random_code = '%030x' % random.randrange(16**30)
    #configuration
    config = twint.Config()
    config.Search = search_term
    config.Lang = "en"
    config.Limit = 1000000
    config.Since = start_date
    config.Until = end_date
    config.Store_csv = True
    config.Output = "twintTerms"+search_term+str(random_code)+".csv"
    #running search
    twint.run.Search(config)
    #convert csv to excel file and append to df_list
    df = pd.read_csv("twintTerms"+search_term+str(random_code)+".csv")
    df['Search Term'] = search_term
    df['Start Date'] = start_date
    df['End Date'] = end_date
    en = df[df['language'] == "en"]
    #delete csv ready for next search term
    if os.path.exists("twintTerms"+search_term+str(random_code)+".csv"):
      os.remove("twintTerms"+search_term+str(random_code)+".csv")
    else:
      pass
    return en
      
def fetch_scrapes(search_dict):
    search_terms = search_dict['Search Term']
    start_dates = search_dict['Start Date']
    end_dates = search_dict['End Date']
    responses = []
    for key in search_terms.keys(): #build a list of futures for async to run
        results = scrape(str(search_terms[key]), str(start_dates[key]), str(end_dates[key]))
        responses.append(results)
    return responses


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Twitter Scrape Starting...")
    #delete any leftover files
    if os.path.exists("twitterResults.xlsx"):
        os.remove("twitterResults.xlsx")
    else:
        pass
    
    #create results directory
    if not os.path.exists('data/results'):
        os.makedirs('data/results')
    
    #pull in search terms
    search_df = pd.read_excel(r"data/TwitterTerms.xlsx")
    search_dict = search_df.to_dict()
    
    #run scrape
    dataframe_list = fetch_scrapes(search_dict)
    
    tweet_df = pd.concat(dataframe_list)
    tweet_df = tweet_df[['date','time','tweet','replies_count','retweets_count','likes_count','Search Term','Start Date','End Date']]
    tweet_df = tweet_df.drop_duplicates(['tweet','Search Term'])
    
    #remove emojis
    tweet_df['tweet'] = tweet_df['tweet'].apply(strip_emoji)
    
    #sentiment analysis
    analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    tweet_df[['Negative','Neutral','Positive','Compound']] = tweet_df['tweet'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(sentiment_score(x)))
    tweet_df.to_excel(r"data/results/rawData.xlsx")
    grouped = tweet_df.groupby(['Search Term','Start Date','End Date']).agg(['mean','count'])
    grouped.to_csv(r'data/results/twitterResults.csv')
    
    #Most frequent words across topics
    extra_stopwords_list = [term.split(" ") for term in list(set(tweet_df['Search Term'].tolist()))]
    extra_stopwords_list = [i for j in extra_stopwords_list for i in j]
    words_list = []
    for team in list(set(tweet_df['Search Term'].tolist())):
        print(team)
        team_df = tweet_df[(tweet_df['Search Term'] == team)]
        raw_string = ' '.join(team_df['tweet'])
        no_links = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', raw_string)
        STOPWORDS = set(list(STOPWORDS) + extra_stopwords_list + ['amp'])
        wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords = STOPWORDS).generate(no_links)
        most_popular = list(wordcloud.words_.keys())
        most_popular = [word for word in most_popular if len(word) > 2]
        perc_list = [[word,len(team_df[team_df['tweet'].str.contains(word)])] for word in most_popular]
        words_list.append(perc_list)
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['Word']= [i[0] for i in perc_list]
        df['Tweets Featured In'] = [i[1] for i in perc_list]
    test = []
    for lst in words_list:
        for lst2 in lst:
            word = lst2[0]
            counter = []
            for lst3 in words_list:
                for lst4 in lst3:
                    if word == lst4[0]:
                        counter.append(word)
            if len(counter) > 1:
                test.append(word)
    test = list(set(test))
    df_list = []
    for team in list(set(tweet_df['Search Term'].tolist())):
        team_df = tweet_df[tweet_df['Search Term'] == team]
        perc_list = [[word, (len(team_df[team_df['tweet'].str.contains(word)])/len(team_df))*100] for word in test]
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['Word'] = [i[0] for i in perc_list]
        df[team] = [i[1] for i in perc_list]
        df.set_index(team)
        df_list.append(df)
    words_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis = 1)
    words_df.to_excel(r"data/results/wordFrequencies.xlsx")
    print("Scrape Completed...")
```

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the issue temporarily by downgrading Spyder. We updated our `environment.yml` and re-created the environment, but if you want to downgrade spyder inside an existing environment you should be able to run this command:

```
conda install spyder==4.2.5
```

Looks like there was a change around June to the Spyder kernel that caused a conflict between Spyder and nested-asyncio. A PR with a potential fix was put up early September, but has not been merged yet. The PR is tagged for the 2.1.2 Spyder kernel release. You can follow the issue [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16183#issuecomment-901614251)